# How to move cursor-to-next from one input to another input and button by pressing keyboard enter in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular6

From the Login design page I have to move the cursor from the `Username` to the `Password` `<input>`, and the same procedure from `Password` to the `<button>` click event so that I can login to my page by pressing the keyboard enter key, in Angular 6.

My HTML code below:

```
  <div class="ibox-content login-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUername" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="loginData.username" autofocus >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="loginData.password" >
            </div>
            <button type="submit" icon="fa fa-sign-in" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="loginData.username == '' || loginData.password == ''"
                (click)="login()">Login</button>
            <div class="login-error-message" *ngIf="content.loginFailed">
                <p>Invalid username or password</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use (keyup.enter) = "focusablePassword.focus()" to input Username and call #focusablePassword to input Password, this would perform the task and same for button as shown in code below.

```
     <div class="ibox-content login-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUername" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="loginData.username" autofocus  (keyup.enter)="focusablePassword.focus()">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input #focusablePassword type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="loginData.password" (keyup.enter)="focusableSubmit.focus()" >
            </div>
            <button #focusableSubmit type="submit" icon="fa fa-sign-in" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="loginData.username == '' || loginData.password == ''"
                (click)="login()">Login</button>
            <div class="login-error-message" *ngIf="content.loginFailed">
                <p>Invalid username or password</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```